# Different artefacts from the same Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a Spring Boot App, that has a feature, which has to be disabled for one distribution, but enabled for another. I've looked into Maven profiles, but didn't get the feeling, that it was the right way to approach this problem.
Is there a way to check during the runtime

```
if (featureActive) {
  // execute some code
}
```

Any ideas on what tool to use to get it done?

Comment: How about using 'activeSpringProfiles', and then annotate the methods for that profile, spring can do this

Comment: @jr593 does that result in different maven artifacts?

Comment: Using spring profiles is the easiest way to go. A profile for spring is associated with `application-{profile}.properties` or `application-{profile}.yml` .. activation via `--spring.profiles.active={profile}`....on command line...

Comment: Spring Profiles is a run-time concept, not a build concept.
In my work life we use spring profiles, so that the same artifact can be deployed to various environments, without having to have seperate builds.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I've decided to use Spring profiles to address the initial requirement.
Instead of checking at the runtime what profile there is, an interface with two different implementations was created.

```
public interface IService {}
public class ServiceImpl1 implements IService {}
public class ServiceImpl2 implements IService {}
```

in the application.properties following line is set:

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profile@
```

Under each implementation you can set a profile, which would look like this:

```
@Service
@Profile("!dev")
public class ServiceImpl1 implements IService {}
...

@Service
@Profile("dev")
public class ServiceImpl2 implements IService {}
```

Now creating an artifact is easy with Maven:

```
mvn clean install -Dspring.profile=dev
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can use maven profile to do that, this is how I do it,

first, add profiles in your pom.xml, like this,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   ...
   <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <env>test</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prd</id>
            <properties>
                <env>prd</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
 ...
```

and then add the bellowing xml in the build section

```
<build>

        <!-- the env parameter is here -->
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/resources/env/${env}/application.properties</filter>
        </filters>

        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>META-INF/</include>
                </includes>

                <!-- if your want to exclude some file, change here -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>env/**/*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <!-- enable filtering, so we can use placehoder in file -->
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <!-- copy the file of specified env folder to the classes folder if there is no same file in resources folder  -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${env}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

        </resources>
</build>
```

third, add a property in properties

```
<properties>
        <!--the spring default placeholder is ${}，so we need to overwrite the resource.delimiter to @ to make maven filter work -->
        <resource.delimiter>@</resource.delimiter>
```

and fourth, create env folders in resources, like this,

```
-- resources
---- env 
------ dev
------ pro
```

and each folder has its own application.properties, and the application.properties will look like this,

for pro env, it can be

```
env.featureActive = 1
```

or for dev env,

```
env.featureActive = 0
```

now you can use @env.featureActive@ in your application.yml or application.properties in resources folder, like this,

```
foo:
  featureActive: @env.featureActive@
...
```

when you use command to build the project, add -Pprd or -Pdev at the end of your command, and @..@ in the application.yml or application.properties will be replace with the env paramters.

```
mvn clean install -Pprd
or 
mvn clean install -Pdev
```

Comment: Bad idea to use maven profiles. Use spring profiles. A profile for spring is associated with `application-{profile}.properties` or `application-{profile}.yml` .. activation via `--spring.profiles.active={profile}`....on command line...